# Can I develop an Ionic app for Windows without using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, windows-10

I am looking to develop an app that can be available in the Windows Store and be used Xbox, Windows 10 apps and Windows phone.

Do I need Visual Studio 2015 to use the tools and compiler to allow me to do this or can I create for Windows mobile on another platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the Windows version of your App using cordova, you will need visual studio express 2013 or higher anyaway.

You can build the windows version by the terminal using Cordova CLI, **so you are able to compile and run** without open Visual Studio.

But, it does not make much sense because with Visual Studio you can debug and work on plugins and other stuffs.

More info here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html

Comment: so does this mean that after installing windows 10sdk and then run cordova buold windows itll work without visual studio installed?